# Wordpress ReferenceError: postboxes is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I already posted this on wordpress.org and im hoping il get quicker response in stackoverflow.

Problem:
Suddenly the menus disappeared in nav menus page. and got this error

```
ReferenceError: postboxes is not defined
```

... i tried deactivating/activating plugins, and it appears this happens when both **Contact form 7** and **Types** plugins are activated. But this only happens on a specific server, it works fine on my development server.

Some suggestions were to increase the memory limit and changing files/folders permissions but all didn't resolved the issue.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by plugin. Deactivated all unecessary plugins, then it started to work properly

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did it and found out Contact form 7 and Types plugin are the issues. Those two are very important to my site. I cannot disable either of them.